Populate Data from another sheet based on data matching with AppScript
I want to populate data in Sheet2 from Sheet1 Data according to match the cell data with AppScript.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iTceKKLdlUj9UNOcwgVChdRKWyvA7_-L5M-bbGJyyJ4/edit#gid=0
I tried the following command in AI but no luck.
Populate data in C column from column J where column H matches $C$1, and column I matches column B.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About Populate data in C column from column J where column H matches $C$1, and column I matches column B., when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I couldn't find the values in the columns "J" and "I". So, I'm worried that you miscopied your question or provided a different Spreadsheet from what you expected. How about this? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?
